# Is it possible to define schemes without using sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

My understanding is that smooth manifolds can be defined either in the usual way (using smooth charts and atlases), or using sheaves (as a locally ringed space which is locally isomorphic to the sheaf of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$). However, schemes seem to only be defined using sheaves. Is it possible to define a scheme as a topological space which is locally homeomorphic to an affine scheme, such that the transition maps are all maps of affine schemes? Another way to phrase the question could be: given such a space, is it possible to recover a structure sheaf defining a scheme?

Comment: I would be leaning towards "no", since for example the one-point topological space has many, many different scheme structures, and we don't have many choices for the charts or maps between them.

Comment: There can be multiple smooth structures on a topological space (as shown by Milnor for $S^{7}$), so I don't see why there couldn't be multiple scheme structures on a particular topological space under this definition.

Comment: This is why the second part of my comment is there - for $S^7$ you have multiple smooth structures because you have a lot of freedom in choosing the charts and the transition functions. This is not so on one-point space.

Comment: Well, you can define a scheme as a certain type of functor, which does not involve sheaves (or even any topological spaces a priori).

Comment: Why not take an atlas containing just one chart, which is a homeomorphism from the one-point space to a particular affine scheme? This is already a maximal atlas, so there should be no need for transition functions.

Comment: Anyway, I think the answer to my question is yes -- given a collection of compatible charts, take a basis consisting of the open subsets of any domain of a chart, and then apply Proposition I-12 of Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: The intersection of two affine schemes isn’t necessarily an affine scheme, which may be a problem for your approach.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- I thought the intersection would be affine. But it seems that it is possible get around this, since a similar  question is answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/31559